# Quick Create Form is not appearing in dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-uci

I've created quick create form of a custom entity **ABC**. In entity properties, I also enabled **Allow Quick Create Form**. Lastly, lookup of parent entity is also placed on the form and marked as **business required**. 
In normal interface, I can confirm that the quick create form is populating without in problem. But unfortunately quick create form is not populating in unified interface.

Any idea why the quick create form is not populating in unified interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Quick create form in the UCI app assets.

[image]

[Read more](https://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/creating-a-model-driven-app-dont-forget-to-add-all-required-entities-and-forms-to-the-app/)